# Multithreading Python FS Crawler

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pool

I've written a python function that scours a filesystem using a provided directory pattern, with optional 'actions' to take provided at each level.  I then tried multi-threading it since some of the volumes are on network shares and I want to minimize IO blocking.  I started by using the multiprocessing Pool class, since this was most convenient...(seriously, no Pool class for threading?) My function unravels the provided FS pattern as much as possible and submits newly returned paths to the pool until no new paths are returned.  I got this to work great when using the function and class directly, but now I am trying to use this function from another class and my program seems to hang.  To simplify I rewrote the function using Threads instead of Processes, and even wrote a simple ThreadPool class... same problem.  Here's a very simplified version of the code that still exhibits the same problems:

```
file test1.py:
------------------------------------------------

import os
import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool

def mapGlob(pool,paths,pattern):
    results = []
    paths = [os.path.join(p,pattern) for p in paths]
    for result in pool.map(glob.glob,paths):
        results += result
    return results

def findAllMyPaths():
    pool = Pool(10)
    paths = ['/Volumes']
    follow = ['**','ptid_*','expid_*','slkid_*']
    for pattern in follow:
        paths = mapGlob(pool,paths,pattern)
    return paths


file test2.py:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from test1 import findAllMyPaths

allmypaths = findAllMyPaths()
```

Now if I call

```
>>>from test1 import findAllMyPaths
>>>findAllMyPaths()
>>>...long list of all the paths
```

this works fine, but if try:

```
>>>from test2 import allmypaths
```

python hangs forever.  The action functions are called (in this example glob), but they never seem to return...
I need help please...  the parallelized version runs much faster when it works properly (6-20X faster depending on what 'actions' are being mapped at each point in the FS tree), so I'd like to be able to use it.

also if I change the mapping function to a non-parallel version:

```
def mapGlob(pool,paths,pattern):
    results = []
    paths = [os.path.join(p,pattern) for p in paths]
    for path in paths:
        results += glob.glob(path)
    return results
```

everything runs fine.

Edit:

I turned on debugging in multiprocessing to see if that could help me any further.
In the case where it works I get:

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 5
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 6
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 9
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 10
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-5] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-6] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-7] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-9] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-8] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-10] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] closing pool
[SUBDEBUG/MainProcess] finalizer calling <bound method type._terminate_pool of <class 'multiprocessing.pool.Pool'>> with args (<Queue.Queue instance at 0x34af918>, <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x3494950>, <multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue object at 0x34a61b0>, [<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-4, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-5, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-6, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-7, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-8, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-9, started daemon)>, <Process(PoolWorker-10, started daemon)>], <Thread(Thread-1, started daemon -1341648896)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started daemon -1341116416)>, {}) and kwargs {}
[DEBUG/MainProcess] finalizing pool
[DEBUG/MainProcess] helping task handler/workers to finish
[DEBUG/MainProcess] removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler got sentinel
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler sending sentinel to result handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler sending sentinel to workers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler exiting
[DEBUG/MainProcess] result handler got sentinel
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ensuring that outqueue is not full
[DEBUG/MainProcess] result handler exiting: len(cache)=0, thread._state=0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-2] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-1] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] process shutting down
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-7] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] process shutting down
[INFO/PoolWorker-7] process shutting down
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-7] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-1] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-7] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/PoolWorker-7] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-1] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-5] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-2] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[INFO/PoolWorker-5] process shutting down
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-5] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-2] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-5] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/PoolWorker-5] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-6] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[INFO/PoolWorker-6] process shutting down
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-6] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-6] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/PoolWorker-6] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-4] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-9] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[INFO/PoolWorker-9] process shutting down
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-9] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-9] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/PoolWorker-9] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] process shutting down
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-4] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-4] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-10] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[INFO/PoolWorker-10] process shutting down
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-10] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-10] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/PoolWorker-10] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-8] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[INFO/PoolWorker-8] process shutting down
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-8] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-8] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/PoolWorker-8] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-3] worker got sentinel -- exiting
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] process shutting down
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-3] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/PoolWorker-3] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] process exiting with exitcode 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] terminating workers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining task handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining result handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining pool workers
```

and when it doesn't all I get is:

```
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 6
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 7
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 10
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 11
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-8] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-5] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-9] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-6] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-7] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-10] child process calling self.run()
```

Comment: I don't see how that code could ever work. You pass `mapGlob` to `pool.map`, but `mapGlob` takes 3 parameters and functions passed to `pool.map` should take 1 parameter.

Comment: sorry, yeah of course... I rewrote the example from scratch and that a mistake.  corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete solution, but I found a way to make the code work in either guise: from the interpreter or as code in a running script.  I think the problem has to do with the following note in the multiprocessing docs:

Functionality within this package requires that the **main** method be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the multiprocessing.Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.

I'm not sure why this limitation exists, and why I can still sometimes use a pool from the interactive interpreter and sometimes not, but oh well....

to get around it I do the following in any module that might use multiprocessing:

```
import __main__
__SHOULD_MULTITHREAD__ = False
if hasattr(__main__,'__file__'):
    __SHOULD_MULTITHREAD__ = True
```

the rest of the code within that module can then check this flag to see if it should use a pool or just execute without parallelization.  Doing this, I can still use and test parallelized functions in modules from the interactive interpreter, they just run much more slowly.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, shouldn't the test2.py look like this

```
from test1 import findAllMyPaths
allmypaths = findAllMyPaths
```

and then

> ```
> from test2 import allmypaths  
> allmypaths()
> ```

Comment: I'm trying to simulate having a global that holds all the paths... It only get populated once when the class is used the first time... In my actual code this global is stored as a class variable, and that class can then use those paths to instantiate an object using that path without having to do a fresh rescan everytime.